# What means "if the foot popped" in an amorous context?

Tags: american-english

At [4:43](https://youtu.be/OPGQAx1PQz8?t=283), a fan Tweeted to ask the guest, Tiffany Young, "did you found [sic] your fairy tale kiss?" At 5.05, Tiffany answers

> I think ... I don't kiss and tell.

At [5:27](https://youtu.be/OPGQAx1PQz8?t=327), the female Caucasian host says

> I just wanna know if the foot popped. OK?

Tiffany Young starts to answer

> My foot

The male host interjects

> Has it?

The guest, Tiffany Young, replies

> Yes it has.

What does this mean? I'm befuddled because first Tiffany answers "I don't kiss and tell." But finally she answers "Yes it has."

Comment: From looking at the comments, I gather that it's a reference to a movie. Beyond that, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what they were referring to:

[Princess Diaries "foot popping"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QawV9tA-50)

Look around 1 minute to see.

So it's not a question of English usage, just a reference to a movie.